# Python (sometimes) missing newlines

Tags: python, io, newline

**Problem**: I have an issue where I seem to be missing newlines in a file generated by a Python script. The script just iterates through predefined atom groups and creates lists of atoms corresponding to each group and prints them.

When I run the script on my machine, it seems to do just fine. However, some of my colleagues tried to run the script and ended up with newlines missing in their code. I haven't been able to replicate the error, but suspect it might be something to do with high I/O load on the machines they were using.

**Question:** Are missing characters a problem in Python I/O? Is there a better way to write these files (e.g. writing to buffers or something)? They can be >100k lines in length.

**Code**:

```
 with open(filename, "w") as output:
     for param in params.keys():
         for residue in molecule.residues.nodes():
             if residue.name == param[0]:
                 rotated_atoms = get_rotated_atoms((residue, param[1]))
                 # Create an identifiable group name
                 group_name = "_".join((str(residue.index), 
                                        residue.name.strip(), 
                                        rotated_atoms[0].name.strip(),
                                        rotated_atoms[1].name.strip()))
                 output.write(" ".join(("GROUP", 
                                        group_name,
                                        str(rotated_atoms[0].index + 1),
                                        str(rotated_atoms[1].index + 1),
                                        str(len(rotated_atoms[2])),
                                        str(params[param][0]),
                                        str(params[param][1]),
                                        "\n")))

                 for atom in rotated_atoms[2]:
                     # Problem arises here, mostly prints newlines, occasionally doesn't
                     output.write(str(atom.index + 1) + "\n")
                 output.write("\n")
```

**Example working output:**

```
GROUP 252_LEU_CA_C 4062 4077 150 0.1 0.5
4080
4097
4107
4127
4146
4161
4173
4194
4214
4082
4099
4109
4129
4148
...
4163
```

**Example broken output:**

```
GROUP 252_LEU_CA_C 4062 4077 150 0.1 0.5
4080
4097
4107
4127
4146
4161
4173
4194
4214
40824099 <-- Missing newline
4109
4129
4148
...
4163
```

Comment: I/O should already be buffered internally. System loading shouldn't affect the output at all. Have you run the program twice with the same input to see if the output was consistent?

Comment: Hmm, it's not consistent, but it's also not missing characters, it just re-orders the lists that are being iterated through. I think I would probably have to dig into `networkx` to find the source of the re-ordering.

Comment: Might there be a problem with the editor you're using to inspect the file, rather than the file itself?

Comment: The problem was observed on opening the file in our Fortran code. I used VIm to inspect the files and it was perfectly responsive, so I don't think there would be any problem there.